# reducing number of maildir folders

Tags: mu4e, email

I recently migrated from emacs VM to mu4e.  Using `mb2md.pl` I successfully (well, modulo a few tweaks) reformatted ~140,000 emails.  All good, really.

However, because of the single-file format of VM, and to keep that size manageable, I had several mail files all relating to a single aspect of my job.  These got transformed into separate maildir directories.  I would like to consolidate these directories into a single one, not just to be anal about it, but because when moving emails auto-completion can't resolve the destination smoothly with my naming conventions.

My question: can I get away with a single `mv` command to reposition all those related emails in a single maildir, followed by `mu index`, or do I need to manually move them all within mu4e?

Many thanks.

Comment: Inasmuch as `mu` can index all of the maildir from scratch within a reasonable period of time, why not just manually move everything where you want it, trash the old index, and begin anew?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is what I was hoping for.  So I could safely execute `mv ~/maildir/work-20{17,18,19}/cur/* ~/maildir/work/cur; mu index` and avoid the tedious job of moving them within mu4e, yes?